# Is it safe to re-trigger a Javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-analytics, dom-events

I'm using Google Analytics and want to track form submissions on certain forms. I want to make sure the call to Analytics completes before the form submission happens, or else Analytics might not register the event. My app already has a bunch of code that happens on submit (possibly submitting the form via ajax, opening the results in a popover, etc).

My plan is to listen to the `submit` event on forms, track the submission via analytics (if the form has the right class), then refire the original event to continue doing normal form processing. This is the first listener that's bound to submit, so it should fire before any others do. Does this work, and is this safe to do?

Here's my code:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  var form = $(this);
  if (form.hasClass('ga-event') && !event._ga_event_sent)
  {
    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: form.data('category'),
      eventAction: form.data('action'),
      eventLabel: form.data('label'),
      hitCallback: function() { // analytics calls this when its done
        event._ga_event_sent = true;
        form.trigger(event);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

  // do other onSubmit stuff here
});
```

Comment: Not that way, `form.trigger('submit')` would just trigger the same handler, that returns false and sends the data etc. in a loop. However native submit, as in `this.submit()` would be different, and actually submit the form, is that what you want ?

Comment: But I'm not doing `form.trigger('submit')`. I'm doing `form.trigger(event)`, which re-fires that same event, which has `_ga_event_sent = true`. And since that's checked in the if statement, it won't cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to re-trigger a JavaScript event?

<strike>In this case, no. You trigger the same event you listen for, causing an infinite loop.</strike>

#### Update #1:

From @lyoshenka's comment:

> The reason I want to re-fire the jquery event is that there's other stuff that I'd like to do on form submission (confirm submit if necessary, submit via ajax, etc) that still needs to happen before the form is actually submitted, but after the GA event is logged.

Thanks for the updated info. This wasn't clear from your question.

Given that your basic workflow is:

1. Send Google Analytics a request
2. More validations + AJAX
3. Submit form

I would recommend having just one `submit` event handler that does all three things. The root problem is you have these three main pieces of code that need to run in a specific order, but they do not know about each other. Instead, consolidate that logic into one `submit` event handler, giving you fine grained control over how these things are done -- especially since you've got multiple asynchronous actions that need to take place.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this);

  var otherSubmitActions = function() {
    // Do other validations, AJAX, etc.
    // Then in the final callback for your AJAX:
    // form[0].submit();
  };

  if (form.hasClass('ga-event')) {
    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: form.data('category'),
      eventAction: form.data('action'),
      eventLabel: form.data('label'),
      hitCallback: otherSubmitActions // analytics calls this when its done
    });
  } else {
    otherSubmitActions();
  }
});
```

Comment: @adeneo: I just saw that. I didn't realize the `form` variable was a jQuery object, not a native DOM object. Updated my answer.

Comment: The code I have won't cause an infinite loop (see my reply to @adeneo in the question comments). The reason I want to re-fire the jquery event is that there's other stuff that I'd like to do on form submission (confirm submit if necessary, submit via ajax, etc) that still needs to happen before the form is actually submitted, but after the GA event is logged. I don't think submitting via the Native API will do that. Or maybe I misunderstood what you're proposing?